# eagerly load an entity object graph in nhibernate

Tags: nhibernate

I am looking for a way to get the entire object graph back from one of my nhibernate persisted entities.  Is there a way to turn off lazy loading in a sessionfactory,session or query?

I have tried setting the FetchMode but it does not eagerly load the entity and child collections.

I just need this for one object to export it out of the database.

Answer (score 1):

You can use CreateMultiQuery or CreateMultiCriteria and keep the default behavior to lazy loading in your mapping.

Take a look at this [article](http://nhforge.org/blogs/nhibernate/archive/2008/09/06/eager-loading-aggregate-with-many-child-collections.aspx) for details.